# escape character not working as expected

Tags: php

I am trying to create html content in PHP and for onclick event I have included a function named uchat for a div. The function takes a name parameter which is a string.

Like below:

```
$name = "Php string";

$echostr .= "<div onClick='uchat(\'$name\')'>
             </div>";
```

But, passing a string value like this causes syntax error when div is clicked. Because, single quote is within a single quote. I have tried to escape it, but it still doesnt work.

The error is this:

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
uchat(\
```

I am not sure how to escape a string parameter and I have come across this problem so many times, Please help if you have a solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaped single quotes will conflict with outer ones:

```
$echostr .= "<div onClick=\"uchat('$name')\">
             </div>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 **clean** and **simple** ways to do this:

**1. Classic concat**

```
    $name = "Php string";
    $str = "<div onClick=\"uchat('" . $name . "')\"></div>";
    print $str;
```

**2. Using sprintf** (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
    $name = "Php string2";
    $str = sprintf("<div onClick=\"uchat('%s')\"></div>", $name);
    print $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
$echostr .= "<div onClick='uchat(&quot;$name&quot;)'></div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

**This works:**

```
<?php
$name = "Php string";

$echostr .= <<< EOF
<div onClick="uchat('$name')"></div>
EOF;

echo $echostr;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
<div onClick="uchat('Php string')"></div>
```

In order to avoid escaping all double quotes and to make the html code more readable you can use `EOF`.

See it action : http://ideone.com/vRCCVH